# Use Azure active directory as custom authentication backend for Django

Tags: python, django, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have Django running on an Azure web app and have followed [this example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-django-tutorial/tree/main/1-Authentication/sign-in) to integrate the MSAL library so that users from the active directory can log in.

This works to the extent that I can use `@ms_identity_web.login_required` in my views to limit access to specific pages only to sign in AD users.

However, what I'm really aiming to do is to use the active directory as a custom authentication backend so that all django users come from the the active directory and that they can all access the admin section.

My employer unfortunately **does not allow me to use any third-party packages** such as [django_microsoft_auth](https://github.com/AngellusMortis/django_microsoft_auth) though.

For now I've read the Django documentation, particularly the section on [Customizing authentication in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/). That clarifies some things, but I am still at a loss about how to proceed as every answer I've found so far recommends using some third-party package to implement some custom backend.

If anyone can point me in the right direction in terms of how to proceed I would appreciate it immensely.